# Send multiple messages in different times Android Java

Tags: java, android, sms

So, I wanna build a scheduled message. But when I try to send more than one message, the other messages can't be delivered. I wonder how to do that.

onTimeSet method

```
    @Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+1);
    Log.d("Current time: ", formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (c.getTimeInMillis() <= calendar.getTimeInMillis()){
        Log.d("Tag: ", "Denied");
        Toast.makeText(this, "You can't send it if it's too early!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Log.d("Tag: ", "Approved");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startSchedule(c);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, MessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

startSchedule method

```
    private void startSchedule(Calendar calendar) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("number", number);
    intent.putExtra("body", body);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm");
    Log.d("Test: ", ""+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    Log.d("Date: ", ""+formatter.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlertReceiver class

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String number, body;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Test: ", "Worked");;
    Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
    if(bd == null){
        number = "";
        body = "";
    }else {
        number = bd.getString("number");
        body = bd.getString("body");
    }
    Log.d("Number: ", number +"\nBody: "+body);
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, body, null, null);

    }
}
```

Please let me know if you guys know what I should do to make things right, thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the other messages can't be delivered"? Is your `AlertReceiver` sending correctly, and they're just not getting to the recipient? Or do you mean that only one of the scheduled alarms fires? If that, then it's likely because you're using the same `PendingIntent` for each alarm set, so you actually only end up with one scheduled. If you really want multiple alarms scheduled simultaneously, you'll need to ensure to use distinct `PendingIntent`s, which you could do rather easily by using a distinct request code – the second argument – in each `getBroadcast()` call.

Comment: I mean that only one of the scheduled alarms fires. I'll try your suggestions, thanks a lot!